# How to read a csv-file stored in wwwroot into StreamReader on Blazor Webassembly?

Tags: file, blazor, streamreader, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Blazor Webassembly. I'd like to read a csv file I have stored into a list, with every line being a string. This is the code I've been trying around with, getting different errors:

```
    public List<string> LoadOptions()
    {

        List<string> returnlist = new List<string>();
        string Optionssource = "Resources/options.csv";
        var st = Http.GetStreamAsync(Optionssource);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(st.Result))
        {
            while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                string data = reader.ReadLine();
                returnlist.Add(data);
            }
            return returnlist;
        }
    }
```

It currently does not work, because of the .Results, which would require the thread to be halted. I'd need the file to be loaded completely, so it can then be passed into the StreamReader, to be read. I'm a beginner and don't know if there maybe is a better aproach to doing something like this/another way to store this data...

Comment: I think you need to read up on and learn what `async`/`await` is:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: @KirkWoll I have figured out how I can make a list and fill it with the desired data. But how would I use that list later? I would like all the strings to be made into options in a select box, but I would have to call the foreach-loop to do that only after the Task is finished.

Comment: Right, you would need to use `await` within an `async` method.

Comment: @KirkWoll Yeah, did that, and that part works now. What I'd need is the possibilty to update the html from the code. Is that possible? In WinForms, I could just call the element and update it, but I doubt that would work now. In also dont think I could use @ because the number of options in the select elements should be dynamic.